# Do units have an irreducible decomposition?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm teaching myself algebra, and I'm  working through a proof of the statement: Let $ R $ be a unique factorization domain (UFD). If $ f,g \in R[X] $ are primitive, then so is $ fg $.

(Start 0f) Proof: Let $ f = a_0 + a_1 X + \dots + a_n X^n $ and $ g = b_0 + b_1 X + \dots + b_m X^m $ where $ a_n, b_m \neq 0 $. Suppose $ fg $ is not primitive. Then its content $ c(fg) $ is not a unit. Since $ R $ is a UFD, there exists some irreducible $ p $ which divides $ c(fg) $. Furthermore, since $ f $ and $ g $ are primitive, then $ c(f) $ and $ c(g) $ are units. So $ p \nmid c(f) $ and $ p \nmid c(g) $.

It's at this point where I get confused. I'm assuming the author here is stating that because $ c(f) $ and $ c(g) $ are units, then by definition they can't be irreducible. And if they aren't irreducible, they can't be written as a product of irreducible elements. But couldn't it be true that an element can be written as a product of irreducible elements, but the fact that the element is a unit is what makes it not irreducible? Sorry if this is a basic question.

Comment: What is this content function $c$?

Comment: But besides, notice unique factorisation is damaged by the existence of nontrivial units. Thus we only consider factorisations up to “associates” and every unit is an associate of the identity. We only talk about (iirc) irreducibility for elements not associates of the identity.

Comment: A formatting tip: `\nmid` ($\nmid$) looks better than `\not |` ($\not |$). (See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4473/whats-a-good-way-to-write-x-does-not-divide-y for more alternatives.)

Comment: By definition, an irreducible element is a *non-unit* with certain properties; so yes, units can't be irreducibles. This also explains why an irreducible cannot divide a unit.

Answer (score 0):

To put Greg Martin's comment as an answer: the definition of an irreducible element requires it to be a non-unit.

If $p \mid u$ where $p$ is irreducible and $u$ is a unit, then we can write $u=pk$ for some $k$. But then $p(ku^{-1})=1$ so $p$ has a multiplicative inverse.